# How do you sort CSV data in Jekyll by a number?

Tags: loops, csv, sorting, jekyll

How do I loop through the following CSV data, sorting in by 'weight' in Jekyll?

**datafile.csv**

```
type,icon,title,description,weight
URL,Weblink,Title,Description,10
URL,Weblink,Title 2,Description,20
URL,Weblink,Title 3,Description,100
```

**The loop:**

```
{% assign cards = site.data.datafile | sort: 'weight' %}
{% for card in cards %}
<ul>
  <li>{{ card.weight }} {{ card.title }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

This returns:

- 10 Title
- 100 Title 3
- 20 Title 2

I want to return:

- 10 Title
- 20 Title 2
- 100 Title 3

Note: I cannot alter the CSV data at the source.

Comment: guess there's a bug in the filter. It seems to be sorting against the string representation of the integer instead of sorting against the integer itself. Suggest you take this up to Jekyll repo..

Comment: Nevermind I opened a [ticket](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6297) regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

As CSV parser return only string, you can :

- modify your spreadsheet to represent zero padded weight like `0010`,
- or, write a plugin that transtype the `weight` key to integer,
- or,try to do it with liquid, but I bet that it can quickly become a performance issue.